# How can I display a variable in Java ME (not text just a variable)?

Tags: java-me

I am hoping someone can help me.  I have a very simple question, but for the life of me I cannot seem to locate an answer:  How can I display a variable in Java ME?  I see TextFields, TextBoxes, ChoiceGroups, etc., all of which don't seem to allow me to display a specific variable (only text).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Below see a snipet of my code - which I might add is not working?

```
  else
  {
      mpg = ((endMileage - beginMileage)/ gallons;
      txtFld4= new TextField ("TOTAL MILES PER GALLON:"," ", 20, (int)mpg);
      form2.append(txtFld4);
      Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrent(form2);
  }
```

Of course, the above code stops in my Java Debugger on the instantiation of the txtFld4. I assume that it is notaccepting the 'mpg' variable.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TextField(java.lang.String label, java.lang.String text, int maxSize, int constraints)
```

You're doing it wrong, do:

```
txtFld4= new TextField ("TOTAL MILES PER GALLON:",""+mpg, 20, SOME_CONSTANT_FOR_TEXTFIELD_HERE);
```

Comment: Sweet! Worked like a charm.  I can stop pulling my hair out out!

Answer (score 0):

What does it mean to display "a variable"? What would it look like to display a ServerSocket?

What you need to do is turn the variable into a String, and it can then be shown.

```
txtFld4 = new TextField("Total MPG: " + mpg.toString());
```

Comment: Note that for a lot of things, you can just do `"string" + variable` and it will automatically perform the conversion - I included the `toString` call in my answer in order to better illustrate what is happening.